# How to get values of modal form antd

Tags: reactjs, forms, modal-dialog, antd

I'm trying to create a form inside modal using react class component and antd, but i couldn't find a way to get the data submited in the form. i tried to console the `event` of the `onOk` in antd modal but i same no data.

i also found an example but it was with function component and hooks `Form.useForm()`

here is the simple if anyone can help : [Simple](https://codesandbox.io/s/1t1m3?file=/index.js)

any hint will be helpful thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide some code of your app? I don't really get what is not working and some code can useful.

Comment: I want to transform this code  https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-modal-form-mymo9  from fonction component to class component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to hide the footer of the modal and add submit for the form exemple :

```
      <Modal
              title={this.props.formTitle}
              visible={this.state.modalVisible}
              confirmLoading={this.state.confirmLoading}
              onCancel={this.handleCancel}
              footer={[]}//this to hide the default inputs of the modal
               >
              <Form
                layout="vertical"
                name="form_in_modal"
                initialValues={{
                  modifier: 'public',
                }}
                onFinish={this.handleOk}>
                <Form.Item
                  name="title"
                  label="Title"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: 'Please input the title of collection!',
                    },
                  ]}>
                  <Input />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name="description" label="Description">
                  <Input type="textarea" />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name="modifier" className="collection-create-form_last-form-item">
                  <Radio.Group>
                    <Radio value="public">Public</Radio>
                    <Radio value="private">Private</Radio>
                  </Radio.Group>
                  //this is the submit of the form 
                  <Button key="submit" type="primary" loading={this.state.confirmLoading} htmlType="submit">
                    submit
                  </Button> 
                </Form.Item>
              </Form>
            </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out myself with limited TS(JS) knowledge using Antd & React framework.

The steps are as follow.

construct an object e.g:

```jss
let obj1 = {
      variableA : "",
      variableB : ""    
}
```

In your form body get the value using

```html
<Form.Item ... onChange={(event)=>obj1.variableA=event.target.value}/>
```

In this case, the event keyword will return the final input value to instances (e.g variableA) within obj1 with given input from different form, which you can operate on after the form submission finish in a quasi-java style.

You can test it by creating `alert(obj1.variableA)` or `console.log` function to see if that's the desired value, in my case it works well with string and numeric input.

As I am not doing front end, so I might make mistakes and do feel free to point it out.